# Wiring a ceiling fan with remote (5 wires) to 2 wall switches

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, light

I replaced my ceiling fan (pull chains for light and fan) to a  TroposAir Starfire ceiling fan.[image]
My house has 4 wires coming from the box, white,red,black and green.  There is 2 switches on the wall that controlled the fan and light independently.  Now with this new fan that goes through the remote it leaves one switch as a dummy as there is just one master switch that controls the main power and everything goes through the remote, with young children this is not ideal.  How to I wire this so the light and fan have their own switch?  The remote has 5 wires going in, 3 for the motor and 2 for the light.

Comment: What make and model is the fan in question?

Comment: It's a TroposAir Starfire.

Answer (score 2):

The fan you purchased isn't designed to be wired with separate switches. It's designed to have an always hot hooked up to the remote unit in the fan that controls everything. If you want a fan and light to be controlled by the wall switches then you need to get a different fan without the remote unit since you can't just bypass the remove unit. There are smart devices out there that allow you to do both but you have to make sure they are compatible with your fan... and they're not cheap.

Comment: Ah that sucks, yea I bought a Bond to control it with my phone.  Ty for the reply